# Change font in excel footer

Tags: visual-foxpro, excel-automation

I record macro "&""Arial,Bold""&10Page" do not work in foxpro excel automation.

What is it should be in pagesetup.leftFooter ?

Comment: Sorry, just google and found the answer.

Comment: Please delete your question, or post your answer and mark it as accepted.